# shell-script: parse seconds with date

Tags: shell

I want to get the date `+%m/%d/%Y` a different number of days ago.

`$(( $(date +%s)- 259200))` gives me the seconds of 3 days ago. The `-d` parameter doesn't accept the seconds to parse it in the format I want 05/06/2011 (error message: `date: invalid date '1307284916'`).

Is there a way to get `date` to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get date on linux to accept a simple timestamp for -d, prefix the number with the @ sign!

```
~% date +%s
1307548153
~% date -d @1307548153
Wed Jun  8 16:49:13 IST 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS X, you can use `date -r 1307284916 +%m/%d/%Y` to get the result you want.  If you are not on a BSD-derived system like MacOS X (e.g. if you are using Linux), there doesn't seem to be a simple analogue of `date -r`.  And traditional versions of Unix usually don't even provide the facilities of GNU's `date`.

If you get really stuck, contact me (see my profile) for a program `timestamp`:

```
$ timestamp -T '%m/%d/%Y' 1307284916
1307284916 = 06/05/2011
$ timestamp -n -T '%m/%d/%Y' 1307284916
06/05/2011
$ timestamp -T '%m/%d/%Y' 1307284916  $(( $(date +%s)- 259200))   
1307284916 = 06/05/2011
1307288704 = 06/05/2011
$
```

Comment: linux uses @<timestamp> to represent the time, so you can use date -d=@<timestamp> to ask it to display on those systems.

Comment: @Petesh: that's interesting.  I'm using an archaic (RHEL5) Linux with `date (GNU coreutils) 5.97` and a copyright date of 2006; it does not recognize the '@' notation.

Comment: the @ notation was added in version 6 of coreutils IIRC

Comment: @Petesh: where do you find that working?  I've just built GNU CoreUtils 8.12 from 2011, and that `date` does not seem to support your `@` notation.

Comment: in parse-datetime.y, it has:timespec: 
    '@' seconds 
      { 
        pc->seconds = $2; 
        pc->timespec_seen = true; 
      } 
  ; 
i.e. it should understand the @ syntax

Comment: @Petesh: yeah - operator error at this end...`date -d @1234567890` or `date --date=@1234567890` or `date --date @1234567890` all work.  What doesn't work is the hybrid `-d=@` notation.

Comment: @WebDev - you're correct to use Petesh's solution, unless you happened to be on MacOS X or BSD.  But please do remember that there are differences between the various Unix platforms, so you can get better answers if you identify where you need something to work.