# What's the inverse of "date +%s"?

Tags: date, gnu-coreutils

Is there something I can substitute for `??` to make this work?

```
> date +%s
1368817693

> date -d ?? 1368817693
Fri May 17...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281080/shell-script-parse-seconds-with-date

    date -d @$(date +%s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
date -d "1970-01-01 UTC 1368817693 seconds"
```

Comment: updated --you need to specify the start of the epoch, apparently. Otherwise I presume it is adding 'seconds' to the current time

Comment: Thomas' comment answers your exact question: replace '?? ' with '@'.

Comment: Beautiful - hooray stackoverflow.  Not sure where else I would have found this - it doesn't seem to be anywhere in `info date`

Comment: That's where I was looking too :)